# NoMethodError: undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error:
ProjectsControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in:
NoMethodError: undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:39:in `project_owner'
    test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'
```

What I think is happening and correct if I am wrong is that when the code goes and search for the projects it finds that the user is not logged in, therefore there is not such a project_owner. Even then the project_owner object should pick it and check that is nil, however that might not be happening.

Projects.Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create]
before_action :project_owner,  only: :destroy

def index
end

def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    if @project.save
        flash[:success] = "Project Created"
        redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    @project.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Project Deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name,:category,:picture)
end

def project_owner
  @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @project.nil?
end

end
```

Model for Project

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  before_save {name.downcase!}
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name && :category, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, 
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Test suit

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

   def setup
    @project = projects(:Flyingcar)
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'Project.count' do
    delete project_path(@project)
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

Any ideas of what it might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This current_user error is due to nil value of the current_user in the project_owner method.

Change this method to

```
def project_owner
  if current_user.nil?
    redirect_to root_url
  else  
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @project.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: That sounds like it mighg be it ! Ill try it out later and let you know thanks Bala!

Comment: I'm not using devise, so I wont be able to do it like that, however current_user shall not have any data as no user is logged in. In regards to the authenticate_user, essentially I have done the same through logged_in_user (first line on the projects controller page)

Comment: @Eltorero1992 I have made some changes on the answer ols look at it.

Comment: Oh thanks! at the end it was just a matter of making a small change to the before_action in the projects_controllers section but thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Neither in `create` nor in `project_owner` the current_user is defined or are you doing that in your filter? Then you have to do that also for `project_owner`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fallenhero, you are right I have defined current_user